# "gnome-terminal --" exits with all forks terminated

Tags: fork, gnome-terminal, orphan-process

I wrote a simple C program to create orphan process:

```
int main(){
  int pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0){
      execl("/usr/bin/firefox", "firefox", (char*)0);
  }else{
      sleep(2);
      return 0;
  }
}
```

I compile this file to `a.out` and run the following command in terminal:

```
gnome-terminal -- ./a.out
```

This opens a new terminal and `firefox`, but after 2s the terminal exits and `firefox` terminates, but I want `firefox` to be an orphan process with terminal exiting.

My program is correct, because when I tried

```
./a.out
```

directly in terminal, `firefox` opens and when I close the present terminal manually, `firefox` is still there. So it must be a problem of `gnome-terminal -- ...`.

I also replaced `gnome-terminal --` with `xterm -e`, but things are the same.

Is there any way to open a new terminal with `a.out` run in the new terminal window and make `firefox` an orphan?(I know how to execute `a.out` in a new terminal and preserve the new terminal after `a.out` return, but I want exit the new terminal and keep `firefox` an orphan)
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is getting killed by `SIGHUP` because its controlling terminal goes away when `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` exits. You have two options to stop this:

1. Do what `nohup` does: Set Firefox to ignore `SIGHUP` by doing `signal(SIGHUP, SIG_IGN);` before your `execl`.
2. Do `setsid()` before your `execl` so that the process doesn't have a controlling terminal. Note that this might result in Firefox suddenly acquiring a controlling terminal later if it happens to `open` one for some reason.